# Find a point on exponental bifurication diagram

Tags: dynamical-systems, bifurcation

There is a unpopular logistic map, that is produced via iterating $x_{n+1} = r (1-x_n^{x_n})$ With rate of growth $r$ as "x axis", being from 0 to $1/(1-{1/e}^{1/e})$ (approx. 3.248869522), and population convergence on y axis, corresponding map would look like:
[image]

I have a question. I want to find that tricky intersection point $r_i$, shown by arrow, and $x_{min}$, $x_i$, $x_{max}$ values, at that $r_i$:

[image]

And also I would like to know, does it has special name, and what are its properties? Is a population at that growth rate $r_i$ periodic or chaotic? Thanks!

P.S For completeness, lets assume starting point $x_0=1/e$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read [The Road to Chaos is Filled with Polynomial Curves](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2974876). While that is written for the logistic family, the same ideas apply to any family of differentiable, unimodal curves. For this particular family, we should define the $n^{\text{th}}$ critical curve $g_n$ to be
$$g_n(r) = f_r^n(1/e).$$
If we plot the first few of these together with your bifurcation diagram, we get the following image

[image]

As we can see, your point is intersection of two of those curves - the $4^{\text{th}}$ and $5^{\text{th}}$ as it turns out. Thus, we can find the $x$ coordinate of the point by solving
$$g_4(r)=g_5(r).$$

A numerical approximation of the point turns out to be
$$(3.12099,0.695916),$$
which  is plotted in the figure.

The answer to your second question is contained in the paper's *Intersection Dichotomy* theorem on pages 644 and 645, where they explain that the point is a [Misiurewicz point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misiurewicz_point) and the dynamics are chaotic.

Comment: https://ia801906.us.archive.org/11/items/AMMTop/The_Road_to_Chaos_is_Filled_with_Polynomial_Curves.pdf to download 4 free, without sms and registration ;-)

Comment: I dont understand after "For this particular family, we should define the nth critical curve gn to be.." but what is that "f"? I cannot figure out how you calculated number 3.12099,

Comment: @xakepp35 $f$ is the function you are iterating: $f_r(x)=r(1-x^x)$. Thus, $g_n(r) = f_r^n(1/e)$. We start the iteration from $1/e$ since that is the critical point of $f_r$.